# On plans reuse in cuFFT

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cufft

This may seem like a simple question but `cufft` usage is not very clear to me.

My question is: *which one of the following implementations is correct*?

1)

```
// called in a loop
cufftPlan3d (plan1, x, y, z) ;
cufftexec (plan1, data1) ;
cufftexec (plan1, data2) ;
cufftexec (plan1, data3) ;
destroyplan(plan1)
```

2)

```
init() //called only one time in application
{
    cufftPlan3d (plan1, x, y, z) ;
}
exec () //called many times with data changing size remains same
{
    cufftexec (plan1, data1) ;
    cufftexec (plan1, data2) ;
    cufftexec (plan1, data3) ;
}

deinit() //called only one time in application
{    
    destroyplan(plan1)    
}
```

3)

```
 cufftPlan3d (plan1, x, y, z) ;
 cufftexec (plan1, data1) ;
 destroyplan(plan1) 

 cufftPlan3d (plan2, x, y, z) ;
 cufftexec (plan2, data2) ;
 destroyplan(plan2) 

 ....
  ...
```

Assume all the data sizes of `data1`, `data2` and `data3` are same. Please ignore the correctness of the syntax. I just need a conceptual answer.

The third implementation doesn't look correct to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all 3 can be made to work.  Method 2 will probably be fastest, as long as the plan fits the data for each of data1, data2, and data3.

You can reuse a plan as many times as you want, as long as your transform intent doesn't change.

Comment: In Option 2 is it ok to create the plan using the createPlan3D () and use it as many times as required ??

Comment: Yes you can reuse plans

Answer (score 4):

As a minor follow-up to Robert's answer, it could be useful to quote that the possibility of reusing `cuFFT` plans is pointed out in the CUFFT guide:

> CUFFT provides a simple configuration mechanism called
>   a plan that pre-configures internal building blocks such that the execution time of the
>   transform is as low as possible for the given configuration and the particular GPU
>   hardware selected. Then, when the execution function is called, the actual transform
>   takes place following the plan of execution. The advantage of this approach is that once
>   the user creates a plan, the library retains whatever state is needed to execute the plan
>   multiple times without recalculation of the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. +1 for you, but I am accepting Robert Crovella's answer as his answer was first.